Inkscape - creating circles with a distressed and faded outline
I'd like to use Inkscape (v1.0) to create circles with a the distressed and faded effect as shown in the image attached 1. I have managed to create the faded regions (right hand side of circle) by clipping areas and adjusting opacity and gradients of the stroke colour.
To create the effect in the rings, I have tried to use the path effects --> rough tools but I cannot recreate the effect. I've attached my attempt for reference 2.
Can you advise on how to create the example image?
Thanks in advance!



Here's one possible way to do it.  These are just the basic steps rather than a full tutorial.

Draw a horizonal line and apply a stroke, then apply a Power Stroke LPE and adjust the controls to make it thick at one end, and thin at the other

Add a Roughen LPE effect with these settings below, and hit the randomise buttons until you get something you like




Do Path > Object to Path to bake in the effects. Duplicate it, move down, select both lines and do Path > Combine. Copy this

Draw a circle and apply the Pattern Along a Path LPE, and hit the copyboard button to apply it to the circle.


Illustrated sample showing steps above and the finished result.

Zoomed in to show the effect

